# Error en validación usando CallBack - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, funciones, callback

tengo un inconveniente con una validación la cual ejecuta una función del tipo callback, explicaré de la mejor manera el problema, tengo una función principal llamada "constructor", esta función dentro de sus parametros recibe otra función, el callback, el primer parametro que recibe es una variable de tipo number, el segundo parametro es una función.

En el interior de la función constructor se crean dos arrays los cuales en su interior contienen objetos, la funcionalidad de este programa es el siguiente, mostrar el nombre del usuario y dirección email en relación a su valor numerico de identificación que tienen en común (id), para mostrar este resultado en pantalla, se realiza una validación, la cual compara los identificadores que contiene el array usuario y el array correo, es decir, que el valor de ambos identificadores coincidan.

Una vez que la validadación de como resultado "true" se procede a ejecutar la función callback, que en este ejemplo se me hizo más práctico nombrarla "f", dentro de sus parametros de f muestro el resultado de lo que deseo.

Al invocar la función principal la condición que he realizado se ejecuta sin problemas, pero, cuando coloco un id que no esta contemplado en los arrays de objetos la consola del navegador me arroja el siguiente error => "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".

De momento desconozco como puedo mejorar la validación para que no me muestre más ese error.

Gracias por leer este tema, que tengan excelente tarde, cualquier recomendación por favor escriban que temas debo investigar para mejorar en este punto.

```
var constructor=function(identifica,f){
        var usuario=[{nombre:'Doribel',edad:35,id:1}];
        var correo=[{id:1,direccion:'doribelpenagos@gmail.com'}];
        
        let usuarioDato=usuario.find(function(datoUsuario){
            let respuesta=(datoUsuario.id===identifica);
            return(respuesta);
        });

        let correoDato=correo.find(function(datoCorreo){
            let respuesta=(datoCorreo.id===identifica);
            return(respuesta);
        });

        let evaluar=(usuarioDato.id===correoDato.id);
        
        if(evaluar){
            f('El usuario es => '+usuario[0]['nombre']+' el correo es => '+correo[0]['direccion']);
        }else{
            if(evaluar !=identifica){
                f('No existe el usuario');
            }
        }
    }

    constructor(11,function(existe){
        if(existe){
            document.write(existe);
        }else{
            alert('No existe');
        }
    });
```

Lo que me indica la consola del navegador es que la valicación formulada no es la adecuada, cuando la condición es false siempre me arroja error.

```
let evaluar=(usuarioDato.id===correoDato.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que el método `find` que estás utilizando va a devolver el primer elemento que haga `match` con la condición y si no se encuentra ningún `match` entonces devuelve `undefined`, y claramente no puedes acceder al valor `id` de un tipo `undefined`. Por eso te tira el error. Tendrás que manejarlo de otra manera.

Una posible solución es:

Agregar una condición para que esa comparación se ejecute solamente si `find` encontró un elemento en cada `Array`:

```js
let evaluar;
if (usuarioDato && correoDato) {
  evaluar = usuarioDato.id === correoDato.id;
}
```

Ese `if` se asegura que ambos `usuarioDato` y `correoDato` existan antes de comparar sus `ids`.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo brindado, pero el programa no ha quedado, al momento de pasar un valor id que no se encuentra contemplado en los arrays, me sigue mostrando el mismo error de antes. => "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".

Answer (score 0):

buen día, gracias por la recomendación, lo implemente, pero no me ha dado resultado, en la invocación a la función principal, al pasar como argumento un identificador que no existe, me continua mostrando el mismo error.

"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".

La implementación del código quedo de la siguiente manera, pero no ha funcionado del todo.

```
var constructor=function(identifica,f){
        var usuario=[{nombre:'Doribel',edad:35,id:1}];
        var correo=[{id:1,direccion:'doribelpenagos@gmail.com'}];
        
        let usuarioDato=usuario.find(function(datoUsuario){
            let respuesta=(datoUsuario.id===identifica);
            return(respuesta);
        });

        let correoDato=correo.find(function(datoCorreo){
            let respuesta=(datoCorreo.id===identifica);
            return(respuesta);
        });

        let evaluar;

        if(usuario && correo){
            evaluar=(usuarioDato.id===correoDato.id);
        
        if(evaluar){
            f('El usuario es => '+usuario[0]['nombre']+' el correo es => '+correo[0]['direccion']);
        }else{
            if(evaluar !=identifica){
                f('No existe el usuario');
            }
        }
        }
    }

    constructor(11,function(existe){
        if(existe){
            document.write(existe);
        }else{
            alert('No existe');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

He modificado algunas partes, bueno, lo que creo que sería la solución, sin embargo mi lógica no es muy buena, y no he podido remediar este punto en la validación.

```
        let evaluar;

        if(usuario[0]['id'] && correo[0]['id']){
            evaluar=(usuarioDato.id===correoDato.id);
        
            if(evaluar){
                f('El usuario es => '+usuario[0]['nombre']+' el correo es => '+correo[0]['direccion']);
            }
        }else{
            if(usuario[0]['id'] != correo[0]['id']){
                f('El usuario y correo electrónico no existen');
            }
        }
```

He cambiado los filtros para encontrar coincidencia con los id, usando funciones del tipo flecha.

```
        let usuarioDato=usuario.find((datoUsuario) => datoUsuario.id===identifica );
        let correoDato=correo.find((datoCorreo) => datoCorreo.id===identifica );
```

Por ultimo, en la invocación, una ligera modificación.

```
   constructor(11,function(existe){
        if(existe){
            document.write(existe);
        }else{
            alert(existe);
        }
    });
```

La restructuración del código es la siguiente, pero ni así me ha sido posible que funcione.

```
   var constructor=function(identifica,f){
        var usuario=[{nombre:'Doribel',edad:35,id:1}];
        var correo=[{id:1,direccion:'doribelpenagos@gmail.com'}];

        let usuarioDato=usuario.find((datoUsuario) => datoUsuario.id===identifica );
        let correoDato=correo.find((datoCorreo) => datoCorreo.id===identifica );

        let evaluar;

        if(usuario[0]['id'] && correo[0]['id']){
            evaluar=(usuarioDato.id===correoDato.id);
        
            if(evaluar){
                f('El usuario es => '+usuario[0]['nombre']+' el correo es => '+correo[0]['direccion']);
            }
        }else{
            if(usuario[0]['id'] != correo[0]['id']){
                f('El usuario y correo electrónico no existen');
            }
        }
    }

    constructor(11,function(existe){
        if(existe){
            document.write(existe);
        }else{
            alert(existe);
        }
    });
```

Sin embargo, me sigue mostrando el mismo error => "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".